# Title: combine a dropdown box with text entry boxes in same form?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to create a form where I can enter data for a new record in a table, using both a drop down list and simple text fields, and then submit it though a .php file.

I have the simple form working with just entry boxes:

[image: I have the simple form working with just entry boxes:]

I have a separate drop down box that works to the point of showing the selections:

[image]

Is it possible to merge these forms into one page, using one submit button, using PHP and MySQL?

Comment: why won't a normal HTML form not accomodate this? How is it different from any other HTML form?

Comment: I think my question is how do I handle the submit to pass it to the database. I'm still learning PHP so the obvious isn't that obvious to me. I've tried running these in the same form and they just don't seem to work. What happens is that when I select one of the drop box items, the entire form is submitted - even though I had not yet filled out the other fields.

Comment: If you're learning, before coding for database manipulation, try `print_r($_POST)` and `print_r($_GET)` to see what actually submitted to your PHP server.

Comment: One other thing that is unclear to me - when I run the drop down box, is whatever text that shows in the top box the text that is sent to the server? In other words, if I select "Elm" and then fill in the rest of the text fields - when I hit "submit" is the text "Elm" sent as the value of that variable? I know this should be intuitive, but my mind just can't seem to make the connection...